# Programmatically Add Objects to a UnityEvent and set the Function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I am trying to add an object to a `UnityEvent` listener and set that listeners function to `Raise()` function as the trigger. Like the below screenshot. That way I won't forget to drag and drop the object, or by chance selected the wrong function;

[image]

I have some a custom `GameEvent` that I use through out my game that contains the `Raise()` function;

```
public class GameEvent : ScriptableObject
{
    private readonly List<GameEventListener> eventListeners =   new List<GameEventListener>();

    public void Raise()
    {
        for(int i = eventListeners.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
            eventListeners[i].OnEventRaised();
    }

    public void RegisterListener(GameEventListener listener)
    {
        if (!eventListeners.Contains(listener))
            eventListeners.Add(listener);
    }

    public void UnregisterListener(GameEventListener listener)
    {
        if (eventListeners.Contains(listener))
            eventListeners.Remove(listener);
    }
}
```

To make my life easier, I have created an Editor script that will populate two `UnityEvent`s for me.

I can find the two custom `GameEvents` I want to add. `OnCameraWillTransition` and `OnCameraFinishedTransition` by using:

```
 string[] eventAssets = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("OnCamera t:GameEvent", new[] { "Assets/_Scripts/Library/Camera/Events" });
```

Then I loop through each of the two events and check their names, and add them to whatever class needs them set. In this example, I am using `ProCamera2D` and it has two events that I want to set. It's referenced in the screenshot above. **This is just an example.** I would like to be able to pre-poulate any class that has some UnityEvent.

```
ProCamera2DRooms pr = m_cam.gameObject.AddComponent<ProCamera2DRooms>();
 
foreach (string s in eventAssets)
{
    string path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(s);
    if (path.Contains("OnCameraFinishedTransition"))
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCameraFinishedTransition");
        GameEvent e = (GameEvent)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(path, typeof(GameEvent));
        // This doesn't work, and I have tried different methods
        pr.OnStartedTransition.AddListener( (e)=> {e.Raise()} ) );
    }   

    //if (path.Contains("OnCameraWillTransition"))
        //Haven't Started
}
```

Is there any way to pre-populate UnityEvent's programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same just a few days ago.
I had an example script made just to activate/deactivate a unityevent:

```
void SetEventTriggerState(EventTrigger ET, EventTriggerType ETType, string MethodName, UnityEventCallState NewState) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ET.triggers.Count; i++) {
        EventTrigger.Entry Trigger = ET.triggers[i];
        EventTrigger.TriggerEvent CB = Trigger.callback;
        for (int j = 0; j < CB.GetPersistentEventCount(); j++) {
            if (CB.GetPersistentMethodName(j) == MethodName && Trigger.eventID == ETType) {
                CB.SetPersistentListenerState(j, NewState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You call it like that (the button that activate the trigger event, event type and event name that you need to change, new state that you need to set)

```
SetEventTriggerState(actionButtonEventTrigger, EventTriggerType.PointerDown, "JumpButton", UnityEventCallState.EditorAndRuntime);
```

I tried to add a line like this:

```
CB.SetPersistentTarget(j, newGameObject); //after the SetPersistentListenerState line
```

But I discovered that there is no way to do something like that (there is only the GetPersistentTarget method and I found no alternative way to change the target object at runtime).

Not sure if you can add it at runtime but there is an alternative way to do everything at runtime that I found:

First you need to implement the interface you need:

```
IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
```

Those are just examples (I'm not sure what you need for the ProCamera2D since I'm not using it), the first one is for the Drag Event, the second one is for the PointerUp event and the last is for the PointerDown event.

After that I just implement the method I want to use with the object I need to use:

```
public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped) {
    currentObject.GetComponent<ScriptOfThatObject>().MethodIWantToUse();
}
```

to decide what Object will use that method I created a setter method

```
public GameObject CurrentObject {
    set => CurrentObject= value;
}
```

And I set that GameObject OnTriggerEnter

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    publicScriptOfMyButtonReference.CurrentObject = other.gameObject;
}
```

This is just an example of how to implement Event without using the UnityEvent.EventTrigger component and just use code.

I will not be able to be more specific since I don't use that Camera script but you should be able to implement a solution with those few things in mind.